# How to generate auto increment field in select query

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment

For example I have a table with 2 columns, `first_name` and `last_name` with these values

```
Ali           Khani
Elizabette    Amini
Britney       Spears
,...
```

I want to write a `select` query that generate a table like this:

```
1     Ali           Khani
2     Elizabette    Amini
3     Britney       Spears
,...
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

If it is MySql you can try

```
SELECT @n := @n + 1 n,
       first_name, 
       last_name
  FROM table1, (SELECT @n := 0) m
 ORDER BY first_name, last_name
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d3a4/3)**

And for SQLServer

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY first_name, last_name) n,
       first_name, 
       last_name 
  FROM table1
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c88eb/5)**

Comment: What if I want to seleect all columns from `table1` instead `first_name` and `last_name`, how can I refer to all? Trying `SELECT @n := @n + 1 n, *` doesn't work

Comment: The answer is `SELECT @n := @n + 1 n, table1.*`

Comment: In MYSQL you may need to initialize @n:  `SET @n = 0;`

Comment: @FranciscoR Please take a closer look, it's already been initialized in the subquery `(SELECT @n := 0)`. The hidden beauty of this approach is that you have a single statement instead of two which is good when multiple statements are prohibited in your client code.

Comment: For an explanation of user defined variables in MySQL, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 41):

here's for `SQL server, Oracle, PostgreSQL` which support window functions.

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY first_name, last_name)  Sequence_no,
        first_name,
        last_name
FROM    tableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3c91/1)

Answer (score 6):

In the case you have no natural partition value and just want an ordered number regardless of the partition you can just do a row_number over a constant, in the following example i've just used 'X'.
Hope this helps someone

```
select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY num ORDER BY col1) as aliascol1, 
    period_next_id, period_name_long
from 
(
  select distinct col1, period_name_long, 'X' as num
  from {TABLE} 
) as x
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @id INT 
SET @id = 0 
UPDATE cartemp
SET @id = CarmasterID = @id + 1 
GO
```