# Set auto-increment field on Oracle select sql statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

I've got one sql select statement on Oracle database where I need to add an auto-increment fields (on the fetched records, not on the database). I've been trying with some responses I've found on stackoverflow:
[How to generate auto increment field in select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555454/how-to-generate-auto-increment-field-in-select-query)

But seems not work. There is for any limitation on Oracle? Anyone know something? Would be great if autoincrements goes 100 on 100.

Thank you

Solved:

```
SELECT A, B, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 100 ORDER BY FDAAID)*100) AS C
FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE A > 15;
```

With *100 counter is going from 100 to 100.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to me you search for `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ... ) AS rn
FROM your_tab
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377788)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

```
SELECT A, B, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 100 ORDER BY FDAAID)*100) AS C
FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE A > 15;
```

With *100 counter is going from 100 to 100.

Comment: `PARTITION BY 100` is useless because it will only create one single partition. You can remove that completely

Comment: Thanks, I will do so from now on