# Is it possible to add id column just result of sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

```
SELECT field1, field2
FROM table 1
```

How can I add an auto-increment temporary id field to query results?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555454/how-to-generate-auto-increment-field-in-select-query) will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in MySQL:

```
SELECT  @s:=@s+1 ,field1, field2
FROM    table1,
        (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40198d/1)**

In MSSQL it would be

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY field1, field2) n,
       field1, field2 
FROM table1
```

Comment: This is fine but as per question the id required is from 0.

Comment: I am taking syntax error. I am using msSql by the way.

Comment: @NuranYüksekce:- Then why you tagged it as MySQL? Wait I will change it to be MSSQL compliant

Comment: @NuranYüksekce:- Check the updated answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: @SUDARSHANBHALERAO:- The question is updated. Check now! And for starting it from 0 you just have to start from `-1` http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40198d/4