# Mysql query: JOINS

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

Transfers Table:

```
ID | storagefrom | storageto 
1  | 2           | 3
```

Storages Table:

```
ID | Name
2  | Kitchen
3  | Main
```

I want to get the following result:

```
Storage1 | Storage2 
Kitchen   | Main
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT storages.name as Storage1, storages.name as Storage2
FROM transfers 
LEFT JOIN storages ON storages.id = transfers.storagefrom
LEFT JOIN storages ON storages.id = transfers.storageto
```

Any tips?

Comment: May be this would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555454/how-to-generate-auto-increment-field-in-select-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT T.ID,
       S1.Name Storage1,
       S2.name Storage2 
FROM transfers T
LEFT JOIN storages S1 ON S1.ID = T.storagefrom
LEFT JOIN storages S2 ON S2.ID = T.storageto
```

> Refer : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20a48/5)

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional aggregation with `CASE EXPRESSION` and 1 `JOIN` :

```
SELECT t.id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.id = t.storagefrom THEN s.name END) as storage_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.id = t.storageto THEN s.name END) as storage_2
FROM transfer t
LEFT JOIN storages s 
 ON(s.id IN(t.storagefrom,t.storageto))
GROUP BY t.id
```

If it's only 1 record and you don't care about `transfer.id` than remove it from the select list and drop the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Just alias your tables

```
SELECT s1.name as Storage1, s2.name as Storage2
FROM transfers 
LEFT JOIN storages AS s1 ON s1.id = transfers.storagefrom
LEFT JOIN storages AS s2 ON s2.id = transfers.storageto
```