# Laravel - receive row number ordered by experience points

Tags: database, laravel, sql-order-by

I would like to receive the rownumber of a user that is ordered by experience points, i know everything but getting the rownumber,

The thing i get is role_id which = 1
THen in the relation table called roles i have id = 1 and type from that id = user. Now i want to display user and not 1 which it is now

I got this till now:
        {{ $user->role_id }}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please specify your relationships and a bit of schema to make us solve your problem, also specify what have you tried yet!

Comment: Maybe this is what you search for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16555527/6884193

Comment: I edited it @SaumyaRastogi

Comment: Not really sorry @YannikBürkle