# Temporary variable assignment / increment in select query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

In MySQL you are allowed to do something like this

```
SELECT @n := @n + 1 n,
       first_name, 
       last_name
  FROM table1, (SELECT @n := 0) m
 ORDER BY first_name, last_name
```

*(Codeblock was originally taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16555527/2279200)

Is there any equivalent approach in Oracle or SQL Server

Note:

1. Something similar can be done with `update` in SQL Server, but I am asking if it can be done with select.
2. Using `row_number` is not an option, since I want to handle how the values of @n are changing.
3. I am aware that SQL Server disallows having both temp variables and table column in select statement.

Comment: *... since I want to handle how the values of @n are changing* this is not clear, at least not to me. What do you actually want to do with `@n`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I mean that I do not want to increase by `1` as it is in the example. E.g. I may add a control block, in the assignment of `@n`, if the last_name start with 'f'. I do not have a real-life example right now, I am just exploring the possibilities.

Comment: You almost certainly still want to use `row_number`, but without a concrete example of what you want, nobody can answer this.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by first_name, last_name)
       first_name,last_name
FROM table1
ORDER BY first_name, last_name;
```

This is not just "another way" of doing this.  `ROW_NUMBER()` is the ANSI-standard method for implementing this functionality -- and you should be learning about other ranking and window/analytic functions.  The use of variables is a hack in MySQL.

This is only the simplest method of a window function.  You need to learn about the other ranking functions (`RANK()` and `DENSE_RANK()`).  You need to learn about `PARTITION BY`.  You need to learn about conditional aggregation/`FILTER`.  I have never used a database with window functions and thought:  "Gosh, I wish I could use variables instead".  I have often thought the opposite.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I said `Using row_number is not an option`, see my comment above on how I want to manipulate the `@n` variable.

Comment: @Athafoud . . . Ask another question and provide sample data and desired results.  That statement is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use variables you must declare them first:

```
    DECLARE @n int
    SET @n = '...'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using `row_number` is not an option, since I want to handle how the values of `@n` are changing.

Oracle - Use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```
WITH ordered_names ( rn, first_name, last_name ) AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY first_name, last_name ),
         first_name,
         last_name
  FROM   table1
),
indexed_names ( rn, n, first_name, last_name ) AS (
  SELECT rn, 1, first_name, last_name FROM ordered_names WHERE rn = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT o.rn,
         i.n + 1, -- Your logic here,
         o.first_name,
         o.last_name
  FROM   ordered_names o
         INNER JOIN
         indexed_names i
         ON ( o.rn = i.rn + 1 )
)
SELECT n, first_name, last_name
FROM   indexed_names
```